# Apache POI: Getting extra column and row count

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to read an excel and get the count. However, even though there are, say 350 rows and 30 columns, it gives me 380 (or so) rows and 40 columns. Though the last value is filled in column 30th and row wise the last filled row is 350th row. It seems to be a formatting issue, because if i delete few extra rows and columns at the end or clear the format for the empty rows and columns, it gives me correct output. Below is the code for getting excel row and column count.

```
int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
int colCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: If a row has row style or a cell is formatted using a special style, then those rows and cells  are present, even if they don't have content. If you want count only rows and columns having cells with content in it, then you have to check this for each cell in that row or column. But why at all? What is the use case for that?

Comment: @alex richter I have to pull data from the excel and put it in a hashmap<String, Arraylist<String>>. Each raw has first column as hashmap key and rest all columns have the values, which i save a arraylist object. Now, here few values can be blank as well and i need to store them too. Hence, I need to know the count of columns, so that i decide when to terminate my loop. If i put a check on blank values, I can't really decide the column count, since there may be a case where a row (say first row itself has all the blank values., which need to be stored in the list.

Comment: Then you need at first traversing all present rows and the cells in them to get the maximum column index of the cell which has content.

Comment: @AxelRichter So i need to basically iterate over some 65K rows with 65K cells, to find the excel size? Is there anything better to improve the complexity

Comment: No, as far as I know. The "Excel size" of a sheet in rows is from `sheet.getFirstRowNum()` to `sheet.getLastRowNum()`. And each row contains cells form `row.getFirstCellNum()` to `row.getLastCellNum()-1`. That's what is stored in `*.xls` or `*.xlsx`. But that does not say something about whether all cells contain content.

Comment: Now the name "HSSF" makes so much more sense...

Answer (score 0):

If you are always sure that empty rows and columns are at the end then try getPhysicalNumberOfRows() and getPhysicalNumberOfCells()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however that's not the case